# error of the assigning unique ptr in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

`server` is an empty class here (commented all members out for a test).
The code below (compiled on Win64, MinGW 4.9) reports this message to the console:

> Application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

What could be the problem here?

```
class server {
public:
    server() {}
    ~server(){}
}

...

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::unique_ptr<server> svr;
    std::thread t1([&svr]() {
       svr = std::make_unique<server>();
    });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
}
```

actually this code produces the same:

```
server* svr;
std::thread t1([&svr]() {
    svr = new server;
});
delete svr;
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Not enough context to know what your code does, please post a complete example. In the second piece of code the `delete` and the `new` happen concurrently, so there is a data race, i.e. undefined behaviour (the `delete` might happen before the `new`, while the value is still uninitialized, so tries to delete a garbage address). In the first piece of code, I'm guessing the `unique_ptr` destructor runs, with the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not taking pointers into account, you start a thread but you don't `join()` or `detach()` the thread, which can cause the behavior that you saw.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a race condition in both cases.

In your first example it is possible for `svr` to go out of scope before your new thread even starts. Since you are passing a reference to it to your new thread, if it is destructed in your main thread then your new thread is left with an invalid object.

E.g:

```
void foo()
{
    std::unique_ptr<server> svr;
    std::thread t1([&svr]() {
        // svr might have already been destroyed, UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR
        svr = std::make_unique<server>();
    });

    // svr goes out of scope and is destructed
}
```

In your second example it is possible for `svr` to be deleted before your new thread even starts. Since it's not initialized to a default value like NULL or nullptr you might end up deleting a dangling pointer.